# How to parse a url from a String in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to parse the url from a String in android. The example String is

```
"This is a new message. The content of the message is in 'http://www.example.com/asd/abc' "
```

I want to parse the url `http://www.example.com/asd/abc` from the String without using the subString method.

Comment: It will be a RegExp then - do always find the url inside the single quote char or do yo need a matcher for urls in general?

Comment: Try with the method that I have posted

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Updated:**

You can use regular expression with [`Patterns.WEB_URL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) regular expression to find all urls in your text.

---

**Original:**

You can use [`Uri.parse(String uriString)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) function.

Answer (score 45):

Use this:

```
public static String[] extractLinks(String text) {
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        String url = m.group();
        Log.d(TAG, "URL extracted: " + url);
        links.add(url);
    }

    return links.toArray(new String[links.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are parsing the links for the purpose of styling them, Linkify is an elegant solution:

```
descriptionTextView.setText("This text contains a http://www.url.com")
Linkify.addLinks(descriptionTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

You can also change the default colour of the link:

```
descriptionTextView.setLinkTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),
                R.color.colorSecondary));
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes its possible.
Try with the following code sample

```
ArrayList retrieveLinks(String text) {
        ArrayList links = new ArrayList();

        String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
        String urlStr = m.group();
        char[] stringArray1 = urlStr.toCharArray();

        if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
        {

            char[] stringArray = urlStr.toCharArray(); 

            char[] newArray = new char[stringArray.length-2];
            System.arraycopy(stringArray, 1, newArray, 0, stringArray.length-2);
            urlStr = new String(newArray);
            System.out.println("Finally Url ="+newArray.toString());

        }
        System.out.println("...Url..."+urlStr);
        links.add(urlStr);
        }
        return links;
        }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 4):

I use this in Kotlin

```
fun findAllUrls(text: String): List<String> {
    return Regex(Patterns.WEB_URL.pattern()).findAll(text).map {
        it.value
    }.toList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new URL passing the string as the argument to the constructor. Then you can use the various methods on the URL class to access the different parts of the URL.

OK, I see that this isnt what you meant. You could probably use a regular expression, but using substring is the easiest method. Why dont you want to use it?

Comment: (the unformatted original post was misleading - your answer was my first thought too - see how the question looks now)

Answer (score 0):

If the string will always be similar, a quick-fix would be to use a StringTokenizer on the single quote.  Then you would simply take the 2nd token.

Comment: The string may not similar always.