# How to get URL from String on Android

Tags: java, android, string, url, android-edittext

I'd like to extract URL from `hi there this is a URL String http://mytest.com`.

I tried to use EditText.getURLs but it didn't work for me.

```
EditText.setText("hi there this is a URL String http://stackoverflow.com");
EditText.getURLs.toString();
```

How can I get URL from EditText?

Comment: Refer the following post to parse the Url from a long string,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384240/how-to-parse-a-url-from-a-string-in-android

Answer (score 14):

Here is the function:

```
//Pull all links from the body for easy retrieval
private ArrayList pullLinks(String text) {
   ArrayList links = new ArrayList();

   String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
   while(m.find()) {
      String urlStr = m.group();
      if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")")) {
         urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, urlStr.length() - 1);
      }
      links.add(urlStr);
   }
   return links;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change input type of your EditText ----   android:inputType="textUri"

and get your url using --- String url=edittext.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: (https://github.com/robinst/autolink-java)

```
  compile "org.nibor.autolink:autolink:0.7.0"
```

Working fine with Android.

Example:

```
  LinkExtractor linkExtractor = LinkExtractor.builder()
                    .linkTypes(EnumSet.of(LinkType.URL))
                    .build();
            Iterable<LinkSpan> links = linkExtractor.extractLinks(String_with_Link");
            LinkSpan link = links.iterator().next();
            link.getType();        // LinkType.URL
            link.getBeginIndex();  // 17
            link.getEndIndex();    // 32
            final_Url = String_with_Link.substring(link.getBeginIndex(), link.getEndIndex());
```